# Synonyms for exclamations of joy or excitement

Tags: synonyms

I am looking for words that convey similar meaning to the following: 'whoopee', 'yeah', 'yahoo', when such words are used as exclamations of joy or excitement, as in :

> 'Whoopee! Hammertime!'
>
> 'Yeah! Holidays!'
>
> 'Yahoo! School's out!'

Perhaps in this type of usage 'synonym' is not the correct term, and I hope what I am asking is in any case clear.

In addition, very localised or period-specific words are very much okay (as long as you can reference it). For example, perhaps in 18th century Bordeaux people shouted "Mercante!" to mean the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're talking about is called an *interjection*. There are many interjections, both positive and negative, so I recommend doing a google search of "positive interjections" for lists of words that match what you're looking for.

See also: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interjection

Also see also: [http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Category:English_interjections](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Category%3aEnglish_interjections)